# How to make TreeviewItem unselected but focused when the user presses up/down arrow keys within wpf treeview

Tags: wpf, keyboard, treeview, keydown, keyup

I have a treeview consists of 4 manuel treeviewItems labelled as shown below respectively.

[image]

Lets assume that I have selected Item1.1 once.

If I hover the mouse over the other treeviewItems, as you can see, it is technically possible to change the colour.

What I want to do is to do the same by pressing Down Arrow or Up Arrow keys from keyboard.

The dedicated behaviour of pressing up/down arrow keys within wpf treeview is as if I am selecting the desired treeviewItem.

I would like any desired TreeViewItem to be selected whenever the user presses Enter key from keyboard while navigating through the treeviewItems by using arrow down/up keys.

I would like any desired TreeViewItem  to be imitated as if the user hovers the mouse over the desired TreeviewItem by pressing down/up arrow keys.

How can I change this behaviour into the desired behavior?

Is it technically possible?

```
 <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="exampleTreeview" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" PreviewKeyDown="exampleTreeview_PreviewKeyDown" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           
          
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="common:MyTreeViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.Focusable" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#a826A0Da"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#a826A0Da"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                      Color="Blue" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                      Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                      Color="DarkGray" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                      Color="Black" />


                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeItemModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock    x:Name="textBlockHeader" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="3,0">
                                    
                                </TextBlock>  
                                                                                  
                                                                                      
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>


                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>

            <TreeView.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Down"  Command="{Binding ControlDownCommand}" Modifiers="Ctrl"  >

                </KeyBinding>
            </TreeView.InputBindings>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ControlDownCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<KeyBinding>(x => OnControlDown(x));
            }
        }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var items13 = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemModel>{
                                new TreeItemModel("Item 1.1"),
                                new TreeItemModel("Item 1.2"),
                                new TreeItemModel("Item 1.3"),
                                new TreeItemModel("Item 1.4")};

          

            this.Items = items13;

        }

        public ObservableCollection<TreeItemModel> Items { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnControlDown(KeyBinding keyBinding)
        {
            Console.Write("HELLO");
        }
    }
```

```
 public class TreeItemModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TreeItemModel(string name)
        {
           this.Name = name;    
        }

       
    }
```

```
 public static class MyTreeViewHelper
    {
        //
        // The TreeViewItem that the mouse is currently directly over (or null).
        //
        private static TreeViewItem _currentItem = null;

        //
        // IsMouseDirectlyOverItem:  A DependencyProperty that will be true only on the 
        // TreeViewItem that the mouse is directly over.  I.e., this won't be set on that 
        // parent item.
        //
        // This is the only public member, and is read-only.
        //

        // The property key (since this is a read-only DP)
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsMouseDirectlyOverItemKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsMouseDirectlyOverItem",
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(MyTreeViewHelper),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new CoerceValueCallback(CalculateIsMouseDirectlyOverItem)));

        // The DP itself
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseDirectlyOverItemProperty =
            IsMouseDirectlyOverItemKey.DependencyProperty;

        // A strongly-typed getter for the property.
        public static bool GetIsMouseDirectlyOverItem(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsMouseDirectlyOverItemProperty);
        }

        // A coercion method for the property
        private static object CalculateIsMouseDirectlyOverItem(DependencyObject item, object value)
        {
            // This method is called when the IsMouseDirectlyOver property is being calculated
            // for a TreeViewItem.  

            if (item == _currentItem)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        //
        // UpdateOverItem:  A private RoutedEvent used to find the nearest encapsulating
        // TreeViewItem to the mouse's current position.
        //

        private static readonly RoutedEvent UpdateOverItemEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "UpdateOverItem", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyTreeViewHelper));

        //
        // Class constructor
        //

        static MyTreeViewHelper()
        {
            // Get all Mouse enter/leave events for TreeViewItem.
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), TreeViewItem.MouseEnterEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseTransition), true);
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), TreeViewItem.MouseLeaveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseTransition), true);

            // Listen for the UpdateOverItemEvent on all TreeViewItem's.
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), UpdateOverItemEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnUpdateOverItem));
        }


        //
        // OnUpdateOverItem:  This method is a listener for the UpdateOverItemEvent.  When it is received,
        // it means that the sender is the closest TreeViewItem to the mouse (closest in the sense of the tree,
        // not geographically).

        static void OnUpdateOverItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Mark this object as the tree view item over which the mouse
            // is currently positioned.
            _currentItem = sender as TreeViewItem;

            // Tell that item to re-calculate the IsMouseDirectlyOverItem property
            _currentItem.InvalidateProperty(IsMouseDirectlyOverItemProperty);

            // Prevent this event from notifying other tree view items higher in the tree.
            args.Handled = true;
        }

        //
        // OnMouseTransition:  This method is a listener for both the MouseEnter event and
        // the MouseLeave event on TreeViewItems.  It updates the _currentItem, and updates
        // the IsMouseDirectlyOverItem property on the previous TreeViewItem and the new
        // TreeViewItem.

        static void OnMouseTransition(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            lock (IsMouseDirectlyOverItemProperty)
            {
                if (_currentItem != null)
                {
                    // Tell the item that previously had the mouse that it no longer does.
                    DependencyObject oldItem = _currentItem;
                    _currentItem = null;
                    oldItem.InvalidateProperty(IsMouseDirectlyOverItemProperty);
                }

                // Get the element that is currently under the mouse.
                IInputElement currentPosition = Mouse.DirectlyOver;

                // See if the mouse is still over something (any element, not just a tree view item).
                if (currentPosition != null)
                {
                    // Yes, the mouse is over something.
                    // Raise an event from that point.  If a TreeViewItem is anywhere above this point
                    // in the tree, it will receive this event and update _currentItem.

                    RoutedEventArgs newItemArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(UpdateOverItemEvent);
                    currentPosition.RaiseEvent(newItemArgs);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```